# Error: cannot find artifact "VRFCoordinatorV2Mocks"

Tags: deployment, solidity, hardhat, artifacts, chainlink

I am getting error while deploying mocks.

code where error is showing:

Mocks:
`if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
log("Local network detected! Deploying mocks")
await deploy("VRFCoordinatorV2Mocks", {
contract: "VRFCoordinatorV2Mocks",
from: deployer,
log: true,
args: [BASE_FEE, GAS_PRICE_LINK],
})

```
    console.log("Deployed")
    console.log("----------------------------------------------------")
}`
```

VRFCoordinatorV2Mocks:
`// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mocks.sol";

`I have checked all spelling twice but ther`your text`e is no mistake I could find in VRFCoordinatorV2Mocks

I have tried deploying multiple times but facing same issue.Checked all things possible from my end

Expecting better feedbacks from all folks

Comment: Hi Teerth
Can you please update your original post with the following:
1) proper formatting of the script that deploys and interacts with the mock
2) the full error message (put in main body of post)
3) the command line script that you run the script with, and which produces the error.
4) link to the repo/guide you're follow or the code you are copying /taking guidance from

The error message is essential to be able to reason about what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> "I have checked all spelling twice but theryour text`e is no mistake I could find in VRFCoordinatorV2Mocks"

I think you may not have checked the spelling carefully enough :)

The filename ends with Mock, not Mocks.

https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/mocks/VRFCoordinatorV2Mock.sol

If that doesn't work please also try:

1. running `yarn hardhat clean` then `yarn hardhat compile`.
2. Then check the `/build/artifacts/@chainlink` folder and look for a JSON file that has the same name as the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock, and check (carefully) that it has the ABI and structure in JSON in it.